# Video files compatibility for Adobe Premiere pro CS4

Tags: premiere, file-formats, cs4

I have Adobe Premiere Pro CS4 in its basic settings. I am trying to merge some .AVI files that a friend shot on his digital camera. The videos play perfect on Windows Media Players and on other players. But in Premiere it looks as though it's stuck. Even after I render.
This does not happen when I work with video captures from DV camera.

Why is that? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the files into a format that Premiere can understand. You should try converting the files into an AVCHD format using a converter.

A free conveter I like is Media Coder

Comment: AVCHD might technically work, but decoding is so much more expensive than a decoding an editing codec, that seeking around your timeline will be very sluggish at best.  You'll also be lucky if you can play multiple streams, or play effects back in anything close to real time.

Answer (score 2):

Premiere handles a lot of video formats without requiring an intermediate (editing) file, so this is an uncommon problem to have.

As with other editing codec questions, I think a good place to start is by reading about the different kinds of codecs: [The ProRes of Premiere Pro?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/the-prores-of-premiere-pro/1732#1732)

It would help us understand your problem better if you could tell us what you can see about the file format when you right-click to get "Properties", or ctrl-click to "Get Info" on the file.  There's a chance that we just need to get the right codec installed for you.

Since it's free to try, maybe download the GoPro Cineform Studio to try reading and transcoding the files.  If that works, then you'll be able to make a decision on whether to keep that workflow, or use a different conversion program.